# Image upload failed using multer

Tags: reactjs, image, axios, upload, multer

I am trying to upload the Image to my Images folder in the react project using axios but its not working:

**Backend files:**

**Index.js**

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express');
const { Router } = require('express');
connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const cors= require("cors");
app.use(cors());

const port = 5000;


app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/auth",require("./Routes/auth"));
app.use("/api/medicine",require("./Routes/medicine"));
app.use("/api/shopcon",require("./Routes/shopcon"));
app.use("/api/upload",require("./Routes/upload"));


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Medicine Backend-app listening on${port}`)
})
```

**Upload.js**

```
const express= require("express");

const router = express.Router();
const multer= require("multer");

const path = require('path');

const storage= multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        const destinationPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..','..' ,'public');
        console.log('Destination Path:', destinationPath);
        cb(null,'Routes/Backend-app/src/Images');

    },
    filename:(req, file ,cb)=>{
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    }
})


const upload = multer({storage:storage});

router.post('/uploads', upload.single("Image") , (req,res)=>{
    res.send(`/${req.file.path}`);

})

module.exports=router;
```

**Front end form to upload Image:**

```
import e from 'cors';
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import "../Styles/shopinfo.css";
import ShopContext from '../context/meds/ShopContext';
import Shopstate from '../context/meds/Shopstate';
import axios from 'axios';



import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

export default function Info() {
 
  const [Province, setProvince] = useState("");
  const [ownername, setOwner] = useState("");
  const [shopname, setShopName] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [shopaddress, setShopAddress] = useState("");
  const [City, setCity] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null)
  
  var random="random";
  const  context= useContext(ShopContext);
  const {addShops} = context;





  




  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setFile("Hello")
    console.log(file);
   
}

const config = {     
  headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(); 
    data.append('file', file);
    data.append('fileName', file.name);
    console.log(data);
    try {
      let result = axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/upload/uploads",data);
      
      console.log(result.response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.response.data);     // NOTE - use "error.response.data` (not "error")
    }
   

    addShops(ownername, shopname, phone, address,shopaddress,Province,City,random);
    





  }
  return (

    <div className="rm-background" >
      <h2 className='bar'>
        Shop Approval Form

      </h2>
      <div className='container pt-0 pr-0 card layout'>
        <div className='row justify-content-center'>
          <div className='col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-5'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className='form-group'>

                <small className="text-body-secondary">Owner Name</small>

                <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='Enter Medicine Name' value={ownername} onChange={(e) => setOwner(e.target.value)} />
                <Form.Text id="passwordHelpBlock" muted>
                 <b>Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers,
                  and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.</b> 
                </Form.Text>
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor=''>Shop Name</label>
                <span className="currencyinput"><input type="text" className='form-control value' name="currency" placeholder='Enter Price' value={shopname} onChange={(e) => setShopName(e.target.value)} /></span>

              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor=''>Phone</label>
                <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder='Enter Category' value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor='' className="form-label">Address</label>

                <input type="text" className='mb-3  ml-3 mr-3 form-control' placeholder='Enter Quantity' value={address} onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)} />
              </div>
           

              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor=''>Shop Address</label>
                <input type='text' className='mb-3  ml-3 mr-3 form-control' placeholder='Enter Medicine Name' value={shopaddress} onChange={(e) => setShopAddress(e.target.value)} />
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor=''>Province</label>
                <input type='text' className='mb-3  ml-3 mr-3 form-control' placeholder='Enter Medicine Name' value={Province} onChange={(e) => setProvince(e.target.value)} />
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor=''>City</label>
                <input type='text' className='mb-3  ml-3 mr-3 form-control' placeholder='Enter Medicine Name' value={City} onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} />
              </div>
              <label htmlFor='file-upload'>* Upload Profile Image</label>
              <input type="file" id='file-upload' name="Image" onChange={handleChange}/>
              <button className='btn btn-success mb-4 form-control'>
                Submit
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




















    </div>
  )
}
```

**Errors:**
[Axios Error and internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5vGw.png)

I tried to change the destination path in the multer.diskStorage function but that didn't work out also.

**My files directory:**
[Project files to check if my destination path is correct or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h17Vr.png)

Comment: What are you getting from the `console.log(data)` in `handleSubmit()`?

Comment: I get a Formdata object , I checked the network tab under the payload section and its showing a binary file.

Comment: Its this error https://imgur.com/a/PJtDjtz